# Show Specific dates in Tapku library Calender

Tags: iphone, calendar, tapku

I have implemented Tapku Library calender in my olympic based iphone app. I want to enable a set of dates(Olympic dates)  on it, so that user can only select those dates.

Don't know how to implement it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following delegate method for get selected date

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d 
{
    NSLog(@"calendarMonthView didSelectDate");
}
```